# How to control number of minor grid lines in ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2

By default, it seems that ggplot2 uses a minor grid that is just half of the major grid. Is there any way to to break this up?

For example, I have a plot where the x-axis is years, and the major breaks are (1850, 1900, 1950, 2000). This means the minor grid points are at (1875, 1925, 1975), which is a little unintuitive for years. How can I make the minor grid appear at every decade?

Comment: you could eliminate gridlines with (in the latest version of ggplot2) `theme(panel.grid.major.x = element_blank(), panel.grid.minor.x = element_blank())` and add them as you see fit with:`geom_vline`

Comment: Since you didn't provide any example data, I demonstrated it with a default `ggplot` dataset.

Comment: @TylerRinker: not looking for elimination. There are other questions about that.

Comment: You asked for 'any way', this is 'a way' to accomplish this.

Answer (score 100, accepted):

You do it by explicitly specifying `minor_breaks()` in the `scale_x_continuous`. Note that since I did not specify `panel.grid.major` in my trivial example below, the two plots below don't have those (but you should add those in if you need them). To solve your issue, you should specify the years either as a sequence or just a vector of years as the argument for `minor_breaks()`.

e.g.

```
 ggplot(movies, aes(x=rating)) + geom_histogram() + 
 theme(panel.grid.minor = element_line(colour="blue", size=0.5)) + 
 scale_x_continuous(minor_breaks = seq(1, 10, 1))
```

[image]

```
 ggplot(movies, aes(x=rating)) + geom_histogram() + 
 theme(panel.grid.minor = element_line(colour="blue", size=0.5)) + 
 scale_x_continuous(minor_breaks = seq(1, 10, 0.5))
```

[image]

Comment: With date objects, it appears that this will work: ``scale_x_date(labels = date_format("%Y"), 
                 breaks = seq(as.Date("1990-01-01"), 
                              as.Date("2016-01-01"), 
                              by = "5 years"),
                 minor_breaks = "1 year") ``  but ``minor_breaks`` didn't work for me when I set the start and end dates inside a ``seq`` command in a manor anologous to that done for ``breaks``.