# Is there a way I can add log gridlines to my graph with RStudio?

Tags: r, ggplot2, gridlines

I'm currently trying to create a *dose-response curve* with Rstudio and I'm using the `tidydrc` package. I was wondering if there was a way I could add minor gridlines, since the `x-axis` is `log`.

Here's an image of what I've got so far

[image]

This is the code I've got so far:

```
tidydrc_plot(Nifedipinedrc,ed50=FALSE)  + 
  scale_x_log10() + 
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=g$Nifedipine-g$SD, ymax=g$Nifedipine+g$SD, x=Nifedipinedrc[[1]][[1]]$d, y=Nifedipinedrc[[1]][[1]]$r)) +
  ggtitle("graph") +
  labs(x="Concentration", y= "Force")
```

I know it's an absolute mess of a code but I'm completely self taught and I feel like I've hit a bit of a brick wall with this because I don't actually understand a lot of the guides currently on stack.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to control number of minor grid lines in ggplot2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12793577/how-to-control-number-of-minor-grid-lines-in-ggplot2)

Comment: For those voting to close due to duplication, the question is distinct in that the question asks for minor gridlines for log-axis instead of regular axis (which the linked answer above is for).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a function that you can use for the `minor_breaks` argument of log scales. The proposed function uses an unexported function from ggplot2, so I'm cheating a little bit. This probably only works well for log10 axis though and you might want to accentuate the major gridlines some more through the `theme()` setting.

```r
library(ggplot2)

# A function factory for minor log breaks
minor_breaks_log <- function(base) {
  # Prevents lazy evaluation
  force(base) 
  # Wrap calculation in a function that the outer function returns
  function(limits) {
    ggplot2:::calc_logticks(
      base = base, 
      minpow = floor(log(limits[1], base = base)), 
      maxpow = ceiling(log(limits[2], base = base))
    )$value
  }
}

ggplot(msleep, aes(bodywt, brainwt)) +
  geom_point() +
  scale_y_log10(minor_breaks = minor_breaks_log(10)) +
  scale_x_log10(minor_breaks = minor_breaks_log(10))
#> Warning: Removed 27 rows containing missing values (geom_point).
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-12-02 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Thank you so much! This definitely helped a lot. I had to make a few modifications because I was actually only after semi-log but this worked great!

Comment: Great to hear! If you have some additions or improvements, consider posting it as an answer too for other people who are looking for similar things.

Comment: Very helpful post been looking for this sort of solution for a week or two